# Why Flow still complains about null values for document.getElementById

Tags: flowtype

Why even with an IF check, Flow still complains about a possibly null value

```
if(document && document.getElementById("myID") && document.getElementById("myID").offsetWidth){
 console.log(document.getElementById("myID").offsetWidth);
}
```

Gives this error

```
   ^ property `offsetWidth`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly null value
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flow has no way to know that the success of first call to `getElementById` means that the later ones will also succeed. For all it knows, reading the `offsetWidth` property could cause `getElementById` to start returning `null` the next time it is called.

You'll need to store the value, e.g.

```
const myIdEl = document && document.getElementById("myID");

if(myIdEl && myIdEl.offsetWidth) {
   console.log(myIdEl.offsetWidth);
}
```

this way there is no way for `myIdEl` to *become* null after it has been referenced.

Answer (score 1):

For HTMLElement (and extensions of HTMLElement like VideoHTMLElement) in FlowType, I'd recommend using `instanceof` to validate the Type and to validate that it's not null.

Also, I don't believe you need to check if `document` exists, that is defined globally in flow (1)*

### `<HTMLElement>` Example

```js
const myIdEl: ?HTMLElement = document.getElementById('myID'); 
if (myIdEl instanceof HTMLElement) {
    // continue 
    console.log(myIdEl.offsetWidth);
}
```

### `<HTMLSelectElement>` Example

```js
const selectEl: ?HTMLElement = document.getElementById('someSelectElement');

// Checks correct type (!null !undefined come for free)
if (selectEl instanceof HTMLSelectElement) {
   const selectedVal = selectEl.options[selectEl.selectedIndex].value; 
}
```

### `<HTMLVideoElement>` Example using invariant

```js
import invariant from 'invariant';

const videoContent = document.getElementById('video-player');
invariant(videoContent instanceof HTMLVideoElement, 'No video element');

// do stuff with video api 
videoContent.volume = 0;
videoContent.plause();
```

1. https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/f3f29f7fd8c5aa73ac5a8a546ccfbc29cd7505fe/lib/dom.js#L1288